# Outlook VBA Dynamic Folder Name

Tags: outlook, directory

I'm still new-ish to VBA, especially within Outlook.So I'm trying to add an input on an excel sheet so I can put the folder name in a cell, and the code will take that named range and make a string which I can use to find the folder path. It is giving Type Mismatch error, and I'm not sure how to get around it. I'd be really appreciative if anyone could give me some advice. My code is below. It gives me the error at that last night. Thanks!

```
Sub List_All_NameSpace_Folders()
Dim myNS As Namespace
Dim myFolder As MAPIFolder
Dim mySubfolder As MAPIFolder
Dim sn, MB, F, SF, SFF, SimSub, From As String

Set F = Range("Folder")
Set SF = Range("Subfolder")
Set Br = Folder.Folders(F).Folders(SF)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Range is an object, not a string. You can use `Range.Value` to retrieve the selected value as a variant (in case of a single cell range).

Comment: Thanks! That was it. I tried to do that previously, but it gave me a type mismatch error. So I removed the "Set" and just put F = range.value. can you help me understand the difference between "Set" and just using an equal sign? What's the real difference and how do I know when I need to Set a value? Thanks!

Comment: "set" is used in VBA when assigning an object to a variable. Otherwise it is a scalar value, such as a string, integer, or a boolean.